# How to interpolate nuxt-link's `to` prop?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've been searching this for a while but can't seem to get it right. I have a basic Nuxt project with the following directory structure (ignore the `fun.vue`) :

[image: dir structure]

The idea is to be able to navigate to a single post with paths like `http://localhost:3000/posts/1`

**This works**, if I manually go to `.../posts/1` I get my page defined in `_id.vue`.

The problem is that, in my index page, I cannot get `<NuxtLink>` to go to single post pages. I have a basic v-for looping over my fetched posts array, like so:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      {{ post.title }}
      <NuxtLink to="`posts/${post.id}`">Link to post</NuxtLink>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I would expect, upon clicking on the 2nd post's link for example, to navigate to `posts/2`, but instead I get `/%60posts/$%7Bpost.id%7D%60`. Why isn't the template string converted normally? I've also tried using a computed value with no success, and the Nuxt Routing docs haven't been of much help.

Highly appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon:

```js
:to="`/posts/${post.id}`"
```

or even better

```js
:to="{ name: 'post-id' }" // post-id or basically the name you gave to your component
```

As shown here: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this
the ":" in front of it will make it dynamic and you can use template literals
in between those double quotes

```
<NuxtLink :to="`posts/${post.id}`">Link to post</NuxtLink>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in my development environment. You also may forgot to add **"/"** in front of "posts":

```
<NuxtLink :to="`/posts/${post.id}`">Link to post</NuxtLink>
```

If you put your code without "/" in a Nuxt "layout", it adds "posts" iteratively to your "URL" and makes the destination wrong:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/posts/2
```

This happens when you click on post 1 and after to post 2.

Comment: Just to clarify, on localhost at least it seems to work even without the initial `/`, just by adding the `:` I had forgotten. Maybe someone can confirm?

Comment: @EmileHaas it depends on how your routes are made. Not an absolute thing but it is indeed safer to prefix with the slash.